# What are some high-ABV IPA's in the Northeast United States?

Tags: ipa, abv, united-states

I'm very familiar with Dogfishhead's series of 60/75/90/120 minute IPA's, Harpoon's Leviathan, and have recently found new favorites in Sixpoint Hi-Res and Resin.

What are some similar high-ABV Double/Imperial IPA's in this area?

Comment: Do you mean brewed in the Northeast, or anything distributed there? Bell's Hopslam qualifies either way, I suppose.

Comment: A question with a much shorter list might be "What breweries are not brewing a double IPA in the NE US?". It seems like every brewery has at least one. E.G., Victory, in addition to Dirt Wolf also has Hop Wallop (8.5%ABV) and Hop Ranch (9.0%ABV). Thankfully, the tide is starting to turn, and they recently introduced Hop Ticket (4.5%ABV), a "Session IPA"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Bluepoint Brewery* of Long Island NY makes **Old Howling Bastard** at 10% ABV (though I won't buy their beer anymore as they just sold to InBev a few weeks ago)
- **Dirtwolf** from *Victory Brewing Company* of Pennsylvania at 8.7% ABV
- At 9% ABV, you've got Double **Simcoe** from *Weyerbacher Brewing Co* of Pennsylvania
- Out of NY, you have **Unearthly** from *Southern Tier*, rolling in at 9.5% ABV
- From NY, you've got **He'Brew Bittersweet Lenny's R.I.P.A.** by *Shmaltz Brewing Company* at 10 % ABV
- *Dogfish Head* makes other IPA's outside of the 60/90/120 Minutes. Give **Robert Johnson's Hellhound On My Ale** a try (10% ABV).
- At 9.7% ABV, *Smuttynose* of New Hampshire makes the **Big A IPA** at 9.7% ABV
- **Stoudt's Double IPA** from *Stoudt's brewing Co.* of PA rolls in at 9.43 ABV
- From Vermont, you've got **Ephraim** by *Hill Farmstead Brewery* rolling in at 10.5% ABV. I've never seen a beer with a 100 rating on Beer Advocate before...good luck finding this one.
- Out of Pennsylvania from *Allentown Brew Works* you've got **Hop'solutely** rolling in at 11.5% ABV
- *Bluepoint* also makes **No Apologies Imperial IPA** at 10% ABV. Again, my discretion about InBev still applies.
- *Flying Dog* out of Frederick Maryland makes **Single Hop Imperial IPA** at 10% ABV
- *Brash Brewing Company* of Taxachusetts makes *The Bollocks* at a whopping 12% ABV

I think that list will do for now. Again, It'd be best to rephrase your question as I was not sure if you meant beer brewed in the Northeast or beer available there. I went with the former (since it should satisfy both conditions anyway).

What you want to keep an eye out for are so called [***Imperial IPA's***](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/style/140/); it is a category of high ABV IPA's

Comment: Maybe you cut it off because it 'only' clocks in at 8%... but how can you make a list like this without the infamous [Heady Topper](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/27039/16814/)?

Comment: Yea, pretty much. I just went though Beer Advocate's list of Imperial IPA's and cut off anything 8 or below. And I've never had it nor heard of it. I'm not a big IPA fan in general; I prefer Beligian wheats, dubbels, tripels, etc. I like beers with spicy and fruity characteristics, but without the hop overload. Well balanced is what I generally look for in a beer.

Comment: Heady has, for some time now, been BA's [#1 Beer In The World.](http://www.beeradvocate.com/lists/top/)

Comment: I'm not denying it; I just never really pay attention to the IPA's cuz I'm not into them. But that list is overloaded with IPA's IMO, they should really rate the beers by style. I don't like IPA's with a few rare exceptions, so it doesn't mean much to me that it's their #1.

Comment: @audiFanatic I'm sure there's an obvious issue of which I'm unaware, but what's your problem with InBev all about?

Comment: They ruin every beer they touch; swap out the good ingredients for cheap corn. Their profits go up and the beer quality goes down. Goose Island is the only exception because they signed a contract which forbids them from changing the recipe for 100 years.